# Getting time delta between two related rows

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a lot of entries in pairs, related to one another by a field `name`, each entry has a timestamp `timestamp_received`. I'd like to get the delta of the timestamp per `name`

table:

```
|id|name|timestamp_received|
|1|A|2016-09-21 11:11:00|
|2|A|2016-09-21 11:11:10|
|3|B|2016-09-21 11:11:20|
|4|B|2016-09-21 12:12:21|
```

desired output:

```
|name|delta|
|A|00:00:10|
|B|01:01:01|
```

What I have tried so far:

```
SELECT name, timestamp_received - LAG(timestamp_received, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id ASC) delta
FROM message;
```

Which does not produce the expected output

```
SELECT fpm_left.name, age(fpm_right.timestamp_received, fpm_left.timestamp_received) 
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM message WHERE id IN (SELECT min(id) AS id FROM message GROUP BY name)) fpm_left
JOIN (SELECT * FROM message WHERE IN in (SELECT max(id) AS id FROM message GROUP BY name)) fpm_right
    ON fpm_left.name = fpm_right.name AND fpm_left.id != fpm_right.id;
```

Which produces the expected output, but seems a little innefficient

Can this be done more elegantly?

Comment: And if there are 3 or more rows for an id? What should the output be?

Comment: A bug report! There's monitoring and testing around more than three rows existing with the same name, so I'll suck up any behaviour tbh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the solution with the window function, you just need to filter out the "other" row. This can e.g. be done using Postgres' `distinct on ()`

```
SELECT distinct on (name) 
       name, 
       timestamp_received - LAG(timestamp_received, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id ASC) as delta 
FROM message
order by name, timestamp_received desc;
```

This will always pick exactly one row per name (the one with the latest `timestamp_received`), even if there are more then two rows per name.

Answer (score -1):

This will return the difference from first and last timestamp_received by name

```
SELECT distinct 
    name,
    datediff(ms,
        (select timestamp_received 
         from message 
         where name = m.name 
         order by timestamp_received desc),
        (select timestamp_received 
         from message 
         where name = m.name 
         order by timestamp_received asc)
    ) as delta
FROM message m
```

Comment: I think this would throw an error instead (in the first round, saying that `datediff()` is not a function).

Comment: my fault.. datediff need a first argument of datepart.. 'datediff(ms, date1, date2)

Comment: Sure.  Did you notice that this question is about PostgreSQL?